# Matrix in report designer using parameter as data source

Tags: c#, report, rdlc, report-designer

I have a big amount of data in a windows form c# application, and i want to generate a report with it. I don't want the report to access the database directly.

The report must have a list of orders (rows), a list of products (columns), and the amount of each product in each order (body). As i said, i have all that information in c#, and i want to put it in the report.

I've tried to use telerik report designer as well, with no result.

Is there any way to use a dataset in c# as datasource of the matrix?

Comment: You don't need to access database directly to use DataSet as a Matrix DataSource. Just add your DataSet as a rdlc report DataSource, make sure to name everything correctly and use it as data for your matrix. if you have issues with that part - show your code to identify the problem.

Comment: Agree. Finally i understood the problem a few minutes ago and i'm doing exactly what you said.